# Removing probably everything from Unity/Gnome in Ubuntu

Tags: unity, gnome, launcher

I want to modify my Ubuntu into a most minimalistic environment that I can, for making it suitable for industrial usage.I need to stay on Ubuntu also.
So I want to remove everything like launcher, panel and etc and change the default keys for launching the terminal, so the operator just can involve with the application which starts at startup already and see nothing else.
I didn't find a solution for removing every feature of Unity or Gnome, so I asked here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most folks when they want that just install Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I get the feeling you are going to want to use 'universe' software anyway; so why not just start with a flavor if you don't want to start with a server base.  If by staying on Ubuntu you meaning keeping to 5 year support software, you'll have fewer alternatives than switching to 'universe' or community flavor tools, as other desktops allow a lighter/simpler user-interface in my opinion than gnome/unity.

Comment: The problem is not with me, this is a task that had been asked from me, and I don't have any possibility to change the distro. They're working with Nvidia boards which are using desktop Ubuntu. So I want to find the files that I need to change and write a shell script for minimizing every product of them. ( plus removing other unnecessary apps )

Comment: You can start by searching for packages that include  "unity" or "gnome" in their names, and remove them. If you think that's too broad a net, it is, but we don't know which you 'need to change', and neither do you.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I'm afraid of crashing problems in the environment.
I just need to remove, launcher, side dock, top bar, system settings for now, and if I know where to read or investigate, or how to do, I would do the rest myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping down from the fully-installed desktop environment can be tedious and error-prone.

Instead, build up from the already-existing [Minimal Image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Comment: I searched a lot, and I think the solution is what you say. Ubuntu Core + LXQT would be the minimalist thing that I can have for this purpose.